# Get ALL links from driver.find_elements by href not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

New to python and selenium webdriver. I am trying to check all the links on my own webpage and use it's http status code to see if it is a broken link or not. The code that I am running (reduced from original)...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
while len(links):
    url = links.pop()
    url = url.get_attribute("href")
    print(url)
```

The html looks like...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href = "https://www.google.com/">visit google</a></li>
    <li><a href = "broken">broken link ex</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I run my script, the only link that gets printed is the google link and not the broken link. I have done some test cases and it seems that only the links that include the phrase "***http://www***" in the link get printed. Although I can change the href links on my webpage to include this phrase, I have specific reasons as to why they cannot be included.

If I can just get all the links (with or without the "http://www" phrase) using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")`, then I can convert these later in the script to include the phrase and then get the http status codes.

I saw other posts but none that helped me get over this obstacle. Any clarification/workaround/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Quick test - add `time.sleep(10)` before this "find" call - do you see the desired result? (don't forget to import time) Note that `time.sleep()` to tackle timing issues should be generally avoided but we are using it here for the sake of debugging only.

Comment: I imported time and inserted `time.sleep(10)` but was unable to print the urls that didn't include the http phrase

Comment: `<a href = "broken">broken link ex`  is not a valid anchor tag, so it can't identify it

Comment: Good catch. I fixed the sample code above. I didn't make this mistake on my webpage and I am able to click the link and access the correct site.

Comment: @Corey Goldberg Were you referring to the missing "</a>" in the line you specified or were you referring to something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the following list comprehension should get you a list of all links.  It locates all anchor tags and generates a list containing the 'href' attribute of each element.

```
links = [elem.get_attribute("href") for elem in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
```

here is same thing broken down into small steps and used as a function:

```
def get_all_links(driver):
    links = []
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for elem in elements:
        href = elem.get_attribute("href")
        links.append(href)
    return links
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I also figured out that the content management system that I use automatically checks each href before publishing and takes out the anchor tag with the direct link in the source code if the link is broken.